# installing anaconda in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, anaconda

Hello I have been trying to install anaconda to work with the terminal but I can't find how to add the Conda command to the terminal I tried looking it up but didn't find anything I recently started using Ubuntu and I am really unfamiliar with everything, I realize I need to find a `$path` somewhere but I don't know what exactly I need to do..

**Edit:**
I need to find how to edit the `.bashrc` file, I can't find it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: to open the `.bashrc` file run this command `sudo -H gedit ~/.bashrc`

Comment: You don't need to be root to edit `.bashrc` please don't do `sudo` with that file it belongs to you. If for some reason you can't edit it the change the ownership with `sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.bashrc`!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To edit the `.bashrc` file, you need to run this command:
`gedit ~/.bashrc`
As [@George Udosen](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george-udosen) said:

> You don't need to be root to edit .bashrc

So there is no need to use `sudo`